# Jmockit NullPointerException with Junit

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I'm trying to run a test that written by another programmer with JUnit in eclipse-indigo,  and he is sure it works but when I try Jmockit there is a failure and I can't find a solution, yet.

I try to change jmockit.jar in classpath but not working. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Edit: When I use "ant test" in terminal there is no problem but if I click run as > JUnit test in my IDE I got this error.

```
Exception in thread "(Attach Listener)" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun.getInstance(TestRun.java:40)
at mockit.internal.state.TestRun.mockFixture(TestRun.java:111)
at mockit.internal.ClassFile.createClassFileReader(ClassFile.java:33)
at mockit.internal.annotations.AnnotatedMockMethodCollector.collectMockMethods(AnnotatedMockMethodCollector.java:39)
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.<init>(RedefinitionEngine.java:86)
at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.<init>(RedefinitionEngine.java:110)
at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.setUpInternalStartupMock(Startup.java:130)
at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.loadInternalStartupMocksForJUnitIntegration(Startup.java:112)
at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initialize(Startup.java:79)
at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.agentmain(Startup.java:69)
... 6 more
Agent failed to start!
[WARN ][load   ] agent library 'instrument' failed to init with result: 102
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgentAndDetachFromThisVM(JDK6AgentLoader.java:130)
at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:80)
at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:41)
at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfNeeded(Startup.java:244)
at org.junit.runner.Runner.<clinit>(Runner.java:25)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:32)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:31)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:391)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:122)
at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgentAndDetachFromThisVM(JDK6AgentLoader.java:123)
at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:81)
... 16 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/runners/ErrorReportingRunner
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:32)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:31)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you post some code please? Preferably something small which still  exhibits the error.

Comment: Actually when I use "ant test" in terminal there is no problem but I click run as > JUnit test in my IDE I got this error.

Comment: maybe ant sets something extra that is not set in the eclipse launch configuration for the test

Comment: @oers in build.xml I added <jvmarg value="-javaagent:libtest/jmockit.jar"/> line, maybe it is related with this but just I do not know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated in your comment you set an extra argument to the execution in ant.
Try setting

```
-javaagent:libtest/jmockit.jar
```

as a VM Argument (its the second input field on the Arguments tab) in the launch configuration for your junit test.

And make sure that the classpath is the same as in ant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the zip file of the distribution around, it should be pretty easy to just debug this and see why it's getting the NPE. Just add the source attachment as the zip file.

Comment: Thanks for answer but actually when I use "ant test" in terminal there is no problem but I click run as > JUnit test in my IDE I got this error.